# How do I Iterate through a nested object and return values in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested-object

I am currently trying to get data points from an API response for use in graphing. I am interested in returning an array of the "4. close" values of the following object.

```
let res = {
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
        "2. Symbol": "amzn",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2020-03-20",
        "4. Output Size": "Compact",
        "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Time Series (Daily)": {
        "2020-03-20": {
            "1. open": "1926.3100",
            "2. high": "1957.0000",
            "3. low": "1820.7300",
            "4. close": "1846.0900",
            "5. volume": "9740990"
        },
        "2020-03-19": {
            "1. open": "1860.0000",
            "2. high": "1945.0000",
            "3. low": "1832.6500",
            "4. close": "1880.9300",
            "5. volume": "10399943"
        },
        "2020-03-18": {
            "1. open": "1750.0000",
            "2. high": "1841.6600",
            "3. low": "1745.0000",
            "4. close": "1830.0000",
            "5. volume": "9596297"
        }
    }
}

// I need this returned => [1846, 1880, 1830]
```

Currently my code looks like this:

```
const parsed = res["Time Series (Daily)"]

const datesArr = Object.entries(parsed).map((e) => ( { [e[0]]: e[1] } ))


function getYCoords() {
  for(i=0;i<datesArr.length;i++) {
  let dateObj = datesArr[i]
  console.log(dateObj["4. close"])
  }
}
```

I used map to turn the nested object into an array of object, hoping that would help me iterate through the data correctly, but I think i've made things more difficult and am getting undefined at this point. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: To be clear `console.log(dateObj["4. close"]` is resulting in `undefined` as currently constructed?

Comment: yes it was coming out undefined. Since been fixed however : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that `Object.entries(parsed)` gives you an array which looks like:

```
[ "2020-03-20", { "1. open": "1926.3100", "2. high": "1957.0000", "3. low": "1820.7300", "4. close": "1846.0900", "5. volume": "9740990" } ], [ "2020-03-19", { "1. open": "1860.0000", "2. high": "1945.0000", "3. low": "1832.6500", "4. close": "1880.9300", "5. volume": "10399943" } ], [ "2020-03-18", { "1. open": "1750.0000", "2. high": "1841.6600", "3. low": "1745.0000", "4. close": "1830.0000", "5. volume": "9596297" } ] ]
```

... so when you map `e[0]` to be the *key* of a new object, you're setting the date as the key, not the `"4. close"` etc. properties from your objects. An easy fix would be to map the entries to the object stored at `e[1]` which contains all the numbered properties:

```js
const res = { "Meta Data": { "1. Information": "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes", "2. Symbol": "amzn", "3. Last Refreshed": "2020-03-20", "4. Output Size": "Compact", "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern" }, "Time Series (Daily)": { "2020-03-20": { "1. open": "1926.3100", "2. high": "1957.0000", "3. low": "1820.7300", "4. close": "1846.0900", "5. volume": "9740990" }, "2020-03-19": { "1. open": "1860.0000", "2. high": "1945.0000", "3. low": "1832.6500", "4. close": "1880.9300", "5. volume": "10399943" }, "2020-03-18": { "1. open": "1750.0000", "2. high": "1841.6600", "3. low": "1745.0000", "4. close": "1830.0000", "5. volume": "9596297" } } }
const parsed = res["Time Series (Daily)"];


function getYCoords() {
  for (i = 0; i < datesArr.length; i++) {
    let dateObj = datesArr[i]
    console.log(dateObj["4. close"])
  }
}

const datesArr = Object.entries(parsed).map((e) => e[1]);
getYCoords();
```

However, as you are only concerned about the values, there is no need to get the entries (which contains both the keys and the values). Instead, you can get the `Object.values()` (i.e an array of your objects) and then map those to values stored at `"4. close"`:

```js
const res = { "Meta Data": { "1. Information": "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes", "2. Symbol": "amzn", "3. Last Refreshed": "2020-03-20", "4. Output Size": "Compact", "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern" }, "Time Series (Daily)": { "2020-03-20": { "1. open": "1926.3100", "2. high": "1957.0000", "3. low": "1820.7300", "4. close": "1846.0900", "5. volume": "9740990" }, "2020-03-19": { "1. open": "1860.0000", "2. high": "1945.0000", "3. low": "1832.6500", "4. close": "1880.9300", "5. volume": "10399943" }, "2020-03-18": { "1. open": "1750.0000", "2. high": "1841.6600", "3. low": "1745.0000", "4. close": "1830.0000", "5. volume": "9596297" } } }
const parsed = res["Time Series (Daily)"];
const datesArr = Object.values(parsed).map((e) => +e["4. close"]); // + to turn string into number
console.log(datesArr);
```